# Adding a free form field to a quote-template

Tags: quote, quotelineitem, quote-template

The end goal here is to create quote line items that have a somewhat broad product name, then a field right below this general name that is more specific. For example:

> **Custom Cabinets**
>
> Unfinished Oak

The specific second line would vary and it would be nice if we could hand enter this value into a free form field when adding the line items.  Is this possible? Any guidance will be very much appreciated!